# curly curly tidy evaluation programming with multiple inputs and custom function across columns

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, tidyeval, non-standard-evaluation

My question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56936372/curly-curly-tidy-evaluation-and-modifying-inputs-or-their-names) but I need to apply a more complex function across columns and I can't figure out how to apply Lionel's suggested solution to a custom function with a scoped verb like `filter_at()` or a `filter()`+`across()` equivalent. It doesn't look like a "superstache"/`{{{}}}` operator has been introduced.

Here is a non-programmed example of what I want to do (doesn't use NSE):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

foo <- tibble(group = c(1,1,2,2,3,3),
              a = c(1,1,0,1,2,2),
              b = c(1,1,2,2,0,1))

foo %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  filter_at(vars(a,b), any_vars(n_distinct(.) != 1)) %>%
  ungroup
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   group     a     b
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     2     0     2
#> 2     2     1     2
#> 3     3     2     0
#> 4     3     2     1
```

I haven't found an equivalent of this `filter_at` line with `filter`+`across()` yet, but since the new(ish) tidyeval functions predate dplyr 1.0 I assume that issue can be set aside. Here is my attempt to make a programmed version where the filtering variables are user-supplied with dots:

```r
my_function <- function(data, ..., by) {
  dots <- enquos(..., .named = TRUE)
  
  helperfunc <- function(arg) {
    return(any_vars(n_distinct(arg) != length(arg)))
  }
  
  dots <- lapply(dots, function(dot) call("helperfunc", dot))
  
  data %>%
    group_by({{ by }}) %>%
    filter(!!!dots) %>%
    ungroup
}

foo %>%
  my_function(a, b, group)
#> Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
#> x Input `..1` is named.
#> i This usually means that you've used `=` instead of `==`.
#> i Did you mean `a == helperfunc(a)`?
```

I'd love if there were a way to just plug in an NSE operator inside the `vars()` argument in `filter_at` and not have to make all these extra calls (I assume this is what a `{{{}}}` function would do?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding what the issue is, but the standard pattern of [forwarding the dots](https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/multiple.html#simple-forwarding-of-...) seems to work fine here:

```
my_function <- function(data, ..., by) {
  data %>%
    group_by({{ by }}) %>%
    filter_at(vars(...), any_vars(n_distinct(.) != 1)) %>%
    ungroup
}

foo %>%
  my_function( a, b, by=group )     # works
```

Comment: Hadn't realized `ensyms` was needed here--thanks. I have a hard time finding up-to-date guides on NSE functions (`quo`, `enexprs`, ``quo_name`, `as_name`, etc.). The programming vignette used to have more about this but now it seems to mainly be about curly curly. It's also hard to keep track of terminology--it seems like they are moving aware from terms like "quotation" and "defusion" toward "indirection," "masking," and "embracing." But maybe I'm mixing things up.

Comment: Agree with @MrFlick that an `across()` solution would also be interesting

Comment: @MrFlick I'm not sure if there is a direct `across()` equivalent here. Lionel will probably correct me, but I'm pretty sure that `across()` operates on one column at a time. If a custom function needs to operate on multiple columns, I would probably group columns via `nest()` first.

Comment: @lost Please see the edit. Turns out that `ensyms()` is not even needed here, since you can just forward the dots. A good up-to-date resource is probably the [Tidy evaluation book](https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/).

Comment: @MrFlick I don't think the issue is in the `.cols` argument of `across()`, but in the fact that functions provided in `.fns` operate on one column at a time. `any_vars()` is [specifically a `filter_at()` construct](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter_all.html), which is where the equivalency breaks.

Comment: I noticed that in the `?filter_at` documentation the `across` translation given for the `any_vars()` example does not seem to produce the same results (I get an empty tibble for the `across` exampe). This may be an unresolved issue with the migration toward `across`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way to use `across()` to achieve this that is covered in `vignette("colwise")`.

```
my_function <- function(data, vars, by) {
  
  data %>%
    group_by({{ by }}) %>%
    filter(n_distinct(across({{ vars }}, ~ .x)) != 1) %>%
    ungroup()
  
}
 
foo %>%
  my_function(c(a, b), by = group)

# A tibble: 4 x 3
  group     a     b
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     2     0     2
2     2     1     2
3     3     2     0
4     3     2     1
```

Comment: Actually, I don't think that `~.x > 0` is quite right. Try `-foo %>% my_function(c(a, b), by = group)` (i.e., negate all values in the data frame).

Answer (score 2):

An option with `across`

```
my_function <- function(data, by, ...) {
 
  dots <- enquos(..., .named = TRUE)
  nm1 <- purrr::map_chr(dots, rlang::as_label) 
     
     
  data %>%
    dplyr::group_by({{ by }}) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(across(nm1, ~ n_distinct(.) !=1, .names = "{col}_ind")) %>%
    dplyr::ungroup() %>% 
    dplyr::filter(dplyr::select(., ends_with('ind')) %>% purrr::reduce(`|`)) %>%
    dplyr::select(-ends_with('ind'))
    
    
}

my_function(foo, group, a, b)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  group     a     b
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     2     0     2
#2     2     1     2
#3     3     2     0
#4     3     2     1
```

---

Or with `filter/across`

```
foo %>%
   group_by(group) %>%
   filter(any(!across(c(a,b), ~ n_distinct(.) == 1)))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   group [2]
#  group     a     b
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     2     0     2
#2     2     1     2
#3     3     2     0
#4     3     2     1
```